# AngularJS filter for nested objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects with arrays of objects in it:

```
var content = [
  { 
    name: 'Foo',
    sub: [{ name: 'Bar' }, { name: 'Foobar' }] 
  },
  ...
]
```

and a template:

```
<input ng-model="search" />

<div ng-repeat="item in content | filter:search>
   {{item.name}}
   <div ng-repeat="key in item">
      {{key.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, I use the `filter` filter to search for string matches, but it applies only to the first `ng-repeat` directive. How could I include the second directive into the search filter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own filter? You can refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters)

Comment: thanks, that'll be more time consuming though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've 'flattened' the object to a simple collection before passing it through the controller to the template, so I don't have to worry about a second `ng-repeat` cycle. The output is

```
[{ name : 'foo' }, { name : 'bar' }, { name : 'foobar' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply a second filter expression to your other `ng-repeat`

`<div ng-repeat="key in item | filter:secondFilterExpression">`

See docs here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: this makes a separate filter, so that the 2 directives are oblivious to each other